# Get response file use ExtJS

Tags: file, extjs, response

I use ExtJS to build the client-side for my program. There's a situation that I want to send an Ajax request to server, and get the response file (binary file, not plain text file, i.e XLS or PDF). How can I get that returned file by ExtJS (I mean that file can be downloaded and stored to client)? I cannot use `var result = Ext.decode(response.responseText)` to receive the result because reponse contains binary data and it cannot be decoded.

The Ajax call is very simple :

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
    url : 'myController/exportFile',
    method : 'GET',
    success : function(response, opts) {
        // What should I do to get the file?
    },
    failure : function(response, opts) {
        alert('Export file failed!')
    }
});
```

Here is my server action to return file:

```
public void sendFile(HttpServletResponse response, String filePath) {
        def file = new File(filePath);
        response.setContentType("application/octet-stream");
        response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment;filename=${file.getName()}");     
        response.outputStream << file.newInputStream();
    }
```

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need the user to be prompted with the typical browser provided open/save dialog box, you don't need to make this call AJAX.

Just linking to `myController/exportFile` from your page should be enough. 
e.g. `<a href="myController/exportFile">my file</a>`

For this approach to work, HTTP response from `myController/exportFile` must include the appropriate headers (namely, Content-type and Content-disposition) that tell the browser "this is file. show open/save dialog" and based on your snippet, I see that you already have this taken care of.

Comment: Great answer! You are the best !! I've looked for this long time and only this post gave me proper answer!

Comment: @amol can you please help me [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8505995/itextsharp-generated-pdf-how-to-prompt-a-user-to-choose-where-to-save)

Answer (score 0):

You can save your file to server's file-system and send window.open('http://your.domain/your/file') to client side... 
where http://your.domain/your/file -link to file

Comment: window.open will lose control to any error handling, not all browser clients allow window.open